# Strange memory leak? NSURLConnection and NSMutableData object

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsurlconnection

I have NSURLConnection to download PNG file from URL. Here is the code:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData {
    if (data==nil) { data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048]; }
    [data appendData:incrementalData];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection {
    [self saveItLocal];
    connection = nil;
    data = nil;
}

-(void)saveItLocal {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docs = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path =  [docs stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.png",self.downloadType]];
    NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:data])];
    NSError *writeError = nil;
    [imageData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError];

    if(writeError!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@: Error saving image: %@", [self class], [writeError localizedDescription]);
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"readyWithGraphics" object:self];

    imageData = nil;

}
```

[image]

Why this object is still living and in memory?

Comment: Two superfluous method calls in one line... `NSString* path =  [docs stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.png",self.downloadType]];` should *really* be `[docs stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.downloadType stringByAppendingString:@".png"]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly nil the NSURLConnection object, as it will be automatically released by it the framework when it's not needed anymore.

Remove

```
connection=nil;
```

Edit: Sorry, I didn't see you were using an ivar to hold the connection. This is not the way it's usually done. Why are you retaining it along with your object? Just create it and launch it, as I said above, it'll be automatically released when the time comes, but definitely don't make it an ivar unless you have a very good reason for it.

Comment: So i should create `@property` ? If i create it local how can I add data to NSMutableData received by connection in `connection: didReceiveData`? `data` should be ivar ?

Comment: That's my point, there's no need for a property or ivar. The connection you'll be using is passed in every time the delegate methods are called, look at the signature: `-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData {
` However, you're right in your NSData should be an ivar, as you will be only receiving the *incremental* chunks once at a time.

Comment: Are you sure? In this document: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html Apple uses ivar `NSMutableData`.

Comment: @SimpleMan Sorry, I meant the mutable version of NSData, NSMutableData.